# What's the name of the white lubricant that children's toys often use?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, tribology

When I was little I would often take apart my toys and found that if they contained any gears or motors they'd always be coated in a white lubricant. What is this substance?

Answer (score 8):

It is *lithium grease* aka *white grease*.

It is often sold in aerosol can packaging. It adheres well to moving parts and tends to work well for long term lubrication of low to moderate load mechanisms.